# Ubuntu 14.04 hidden in Windows 10?

Tags: dual-boot

I have a Lenovo Laptop with 120GB SSD.
I have it dual booting with Windows 10 (Build 1709 has just installed).
I have Ubuntu 16.04 as my other preferred OS.

Looking through my files to make space I found a folder in Windows:  c:\ubuntu
This is 15GB in size.

In Windows 10 App Manager there is an app which claims to be Ubuntu and details say : 14.04-rev286.

I want to know, is the folder and app just showing my dual boot option or is there another copy of Ubuntu 14.04 cluttering up my hard drive and can I delete it (delete folder/ uninstall App)

Comment: This might be the "[Windows subsystem for Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Subsystem_for_Linux)" - windows nowdays has a linux environment which can be installed directly within windows. I'f you've installed 16.04 as dual boot, it lives on its own partition - you won't be able to see it from within Windows. So yes, you should be fine uninstalling the app, but just deleting the folder may not be a good idea, uninstalling the app should do that.

Comment: I'll give it a go....